# Creating automated script to simulate an app's http requests

Tags: java, http, automation, request

I'm working on a Java simple code that automates the requests and responses executed for a specific application.
The given app is an .exe file that makes HTTP requests to a web server on port 8080 for the login and for the user interaction (for example, the user searches for a set of articles).

I have used Wireshark to determine the headers sent by the app and it works fine. The problem appears after a few tens of requests (made at a difference of 10-15 seconds, random basically), the server will no longer respond (i believe the IP is banned, and the server will  allow requests on the 8080 port) for 12-24 hours.
I basically used Html Unit (and also tested with javax default classes HttpConnection, etc) to simulate the requests and compared the headers send by the .exe app and my java app: they are identical. But it works fine for 30-40 (sometimes even more) but then I get errors like Time out or Socket Closed exceptions.

I know that this issue may be triggered by the way requests are made (number per day or other time interval, order of sending them, etc), but I would like to know if i'm missing something for my java code: setting the request's http headers identical is enough to "impersonate" the .exe app?

Comment: Was the web server code written by you? Or do you have access to it? Perhaps the problem is in the server code (for example, not closing DB connections may exhaust the connection pool). If you can debug the server, you can find out the error that occurs there.

Comment: No, I have no specific knowledge of the web server.